# GET http://localhost:8100/Content.html 404 (Not Found)

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework, gulp, google-maps-markers

I'm using ionic framework and testing my app with ionic serve in chrome. Ionic uses gulp but there's nothing about the html files in gulpfile.js
I can't find them in the inspector under the Sources tab like the css and js files. 
What I'm trying to do is to add labels for angular google map markers like this:
- I have this url in ui-gmap-window templateUrl="'views/markerLabelContent.html'"

```
<div class="col" id="map_canvas" style="padding:2px !important;">
  <ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" options="options">

    <ui-gmap-marker ng-repeat="marker in map.markers"coords="marker.coords" idkey="marker.id">
      <ui-gmap-window options="marker.labelOptions" show="marker.labelOptions.show" closeClick="closeWindow" templateUrl="'views/markerLabelContent.html'" templateParameter="labelParameters">
      </ui-gmap-window>
    </ui-gmap-marker>

  </ui-gmap-google-map>
</div>
```

Initialize the page with a function:

```
$scope.initialize = function () {
  $scope.content= contentService.all();

  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.content.length; i++) {
    var marker = {
      id: $scope.content[i].id,
      coords: {
        latitude: $scope.content[i].lat,
        longitude: $scope.content[i].lng
      },
      labelOptions: {
        position: {
          lat: $scope.content[i].lat,
          lng: $scope.content[i].lng
        },
        show: true
      },
      labelParameters: {
        shopName: $scope.content[i].shop_name
      }
    };

    $scope.map.markers.push(marker);
  }
}
```

Map works fine as well as the markers. I'm suspecting the build system moves files. The templates are in the same folder.

Comment: check the path, you may need to put in the absolute path but its hard to say without knowing your file structure. the path is relative to wherever the file it is referenced from is located.

Comment: You were right. It needed the whole url like app/views/xy.html I wonder if it works on a real device too. Thanks a lot!

Comment: no problem! I ran into this myself a while back. it should work on a real device as well.